# weird array string output

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am new to C and I want to make a library with the inputs are title, author and the book's publishing year. and outputs are shelf code(shortened title), book code(first letter of book title and first letter of author), title, author and book's publishing year. if i input "C How to Programming" in title, so the shelf code should printed "CHtP". and the question is, when i print the shelf code, there are weird symbol printed in my program. Please help..

```
int main() 
{
    char title[5][200], author[5][200], shelf[5][200], bookcode[5][200], temp[200];
    int year;

    printf("Welcome to Blues Library\n");
    printf("============================\n\n");

    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        printf("Book's Title = ");
        scanf("%[^\n]s", &title[i]); fflush(stdin);
        printf("Book's Author = ");
        scanf("%[^\n]s", &author[i]); fflush(stdin);
        printf("Book's publishing year = ");
        scanf("%d", &year); fflush(stdin);
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n");
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < strlen(title[i]); j++)
        {
            if(j == 0)
            {
                shelf[i][j] = title[i][j];
            }
            else if(title[i][j-1] == ' ')
            {
                shelf[i][j] = title[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    //print
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        printf("Book's Title = %s\n", title[i]);
        printf("Book's Author = %s\n", author[i]);
        printf("Book's publishing year = %d\n", year);
        printf("Shelf Code = %s\n", shelf[i]);

    }

}
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is bad (undefined behaviour).

Comment: even badder: `scanf("%[^\n]s", &title[i])` should be `scanf("%[^\n]s", title[i])`. same thing for `author` and all strings BTW

Comment: first it's better to have a working program pasted :-) second the issue is in your `scanf`; since you're entering strings for `title` and `author` (which are designated by character arrays) the `&` is not needed in front of them in `scanf`. as @PaulR said you should not use `fflush(stdin)` ... there's no need for it

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you should probably learn about *structures*.

Comment: Please read this: [mcve]

Comment: And please show an example of input and expected output

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you never terminate the strings in `shelf[][]` and you're not tracking the index into `shelf[i][]` correctly.  (It's also not clear where you declare `i` and `j`.)  Try this inner loop instead:

```
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    int k = 0;

    for (j = 0; j < strlen(title[i]); j++)
    {
        if (j == 0 || title[i][j - 1] == ' ')
        {
            shelf[i][k++] = title[i][j];
        }
    }

    shelf[i][k] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: it's working. Thanks for your help!! i really appreciate it